# Get the value of a variable who's name matches this string?

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit new at Javascript... What I need to do is get a variable by it's name, which the code can get as a string, but that string is going to be different depending on input etc. My searching hasn't gotten anything so far, but maybe I don't know the correct terms to use to describe this. This is what I made so far:

```
var 1name = 'test';                          // This part is added by php, and
var 1data = 'THIS IS TEST TABLE RAWR';       // the variable names end up being
var 2name = 'etc';                           // a number followed by "name", etc.
var 2data = 'MORE PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE';
```

later on:

```
function editTable(id) {
if (id != null) {
    document.getElementById('name').value = window[id + "name"];        
    }
}
```

and a button:

```
<input type='button' value='Edit'  onclick="editTable(document.getElementById('table').value)" />
```

The button grabs the value of a form field, which will match the number of one set of the variables added from the php.  How can I get this to work?  I've already made sure the variables are getting inserted into the page, and that the button gets a value that matches.
Can you see what I was going for or do you need more explanation?

Comment: Note, JavaScript variables can not start with numbers.

Comment: oh damn, is that my problem?
EDIT: Yeah, that just completely solved my problem... switched around the variable names to "name#" and it works... Now how do I close the question? :P

Comment: That might be, properties _may_ have numbers though, so for example `window["1a"] = 15;` is perfectly legal while doing `var 1a;` is not. The two statements appear similar but are different for several reasons (this being one). Let me know if your code works if you rename your variables

Comment: Frayer - to close the question, ideally @BenjaminGruenbaum would copy his comment into an answer so that you could then mark that answer as accepted. BTW, if you want to respond to another user who has commented, be sure to enter "@" and their user name within the comment (should pop up an auto-complete as you type it).

Answer (score 1):

Variables cannot start with numbers. Personally I think you should use an array like this:

```
var data = [
    {name:"text",data:"THIS IS TEST TABLE RAWR"},
    {name:"etc",data:"MORE PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE"}
];
```

Since you've mentioned PHP outputting this, look at [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode). Then you could just have:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

Assuming, of course, that `$data` is your array structure.